# Evaluate the double integral (x+y)dA where D is the region bounded by the curves x=y^2 and x+2y = 48

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I solved for y and got -8 and 6. So I took the integral from that and the two equations. However, I keep getting the wrong answer. I've done it twice now.

x=y^2 and x=48-2y
48-2y=y^2
y^2+2y-48=0
y = -8 and 6

so i took the integral from -8 to 6 and 48-2y to y^2 of (x+y) dxdy
taking the first integral I got x^2/2 +xy from 48-2y to y^2
Solving this I got 1152y + 48y - y^4/2 - y^3
I then took the integral of this from 6 to -8. The answer I got then was 60508/5.

I thought maybe I I needed to flip 48-2y to the bottom of the integral and flip y^2 to the top of the integral. I did this and solved but the answer was still wrong.

Comment: if you tell us what the right answer is then we can see if we can find it for you!

Comment: Draw a careful picture. It will be easier if you integrate first with respect to $x$.

Comment: They have given us a picture.

Answer (score 1):

The integral set up is:  Int(y = -8 to y = 6)Int( x = y^2 to x = 48 - 2y)(x + y)dxdy. You can work out the details.